# How to combine JDBC statement with EntityManager?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, entitymanager

I created the entity classes of my database with NetBeans. I believe I know how to use EntityManager

```
(Class) db.createNamedQuery(String name);
```

but I don't know where to put the statement (database link, login, password) so I learned how to query with

```
(JDBC4ResultSet) statement.executeQuery(String query);
```

but it returns the set which I don't know how to transform into Entity class... something like

```
(Class) statement.execureQuery(String query).toEntity(Class);
```

would be nice. ;-)

Comment: Don't want to be rude, but I think you don't know how to use EntityManager. EntityManager uses JDBC , but doesn't return JDBC Result Sets. It returns a List of entities, or a List of Object[] depending on the JPQL query. If you're using JPA, you shouldn't have to deal with JDBC anymore. Find a good JPA tutorial, because you have not grasped the basics.

Comment: yeah, I probably just Googled wrong, I was pretty sure that I need to manage JDBC manually and was searching for such a tutorials which obviously doesn't exists. ;-)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, First you need to get an `EntityManager` from entity manager factory with your `persistance unit` name (which will be configured in persistance.xml). And then you create an `EntityManager`.

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistance_unit_name");
    EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("namedQueryName"); //this returns a query
    List<ENTITIY> result = query.getResultList();
```

This is just an heads up, You can google 'jpa example' to find out more working examples.